# Symbolic computation in R?

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to do symbolic computation in R?

For example,

I was hoping to get the inverse of a symbolic covariance matrix of 3D Gaussian distribution.

Also can I do symbolic integration and differentiation in R?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  There is the [Ryacas package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/index.html) which is hosted on Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/ryacas/).  Ryacas has recently been expanded/converted to the rMathpiper package which is hosted [here](http://code.google.com/p/rmathpiper/).  I have used Ryacas and it is straightforward, but you will need to install [Yacas](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/) in order for it to work (Yacas does all the heavy lifting; Ryacas is just an R interface to Yacas).

There is also the rSymPy project hosted on Google Code [here](http://rsympy.googlecode.com/).  I haven't tried this one.  The idea is similar, though, link to the sympy CAS which does the symbolic work.

Answer (score 19):

Some things are also in base R --- see `help(deriv)` or `help(D)`.

A simple example from that help page:

```
R> trig.exp <- expression(sin(cos(x + y^2)))
R> ( D.sc <- D(trig.exp, "x") )
-(cos(cos(x + y^2)) * sin(x + y^2))
R>      all.equal(D(trig.exp[[1]], "x"), D.sc)
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Answer (score 6):

It makes more sense to use a "real" CAS like [Maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_%28software%29).

Comment: Well the original question was about R though.